# Scala implicit and type classes across multiple projects

Tags: scala, implicit

Dear Scala developers,

## Context

I have two Scala projects, called `core` and `infra`. The `core` project contains trait definitions, while `infra` contains the concrete implementations of those. Therefore, `infra` depends on `core`.

In the `core` project, I have this trait that uses cake pattern.

```
trait GetSectionsOfTypeComp {
  def sectionsOfType[SectionType <: SoftwareSection](implicit evidence: GetSectionsOfType[SectionType]): GetSectionsOfType[SectionType]

  trait GetSectionsOfType[SectionType <: SoftwareSection] {
    def getAll(dataStream: InputStream): Seq[SectionType]
  }
}
```

where `SoftwareSection` is a trait with one child:

```
sealed trait SoftwareSection {
  def name: String
  def rawAddress: SoftwareAddress
  def rawSize: Long
}

case class CodeSoftwareSection(name: String, rawAddress: SoftwareAddress, rawSize: Long) extends SoftwareSection
```

In the `infra` project, I would like to segregate the logic depending on the type parameter of the method `GetSectionsOfType.sectionsOfType`. Therefore, I use type classes:

```
trait PeParserGetSectionsOfCodeComp extends GetSectionsOfTypeComp {
  implicit val foo: GetSectionsOfType[CodeSoftwareSection] = GetSectionOfCode

  override def sectionsOfType[SectionType <: SoftwareSection](implicit evidence: GetSectionsOfType[SectionType]): GetSectionsOfType[SectionType] = evidence

  implicit object GetSectionOfCode extends GetSectionsOfType[CodeSoftwareSection] {
    override def getAll(dataStream: InputStream): Seq[CodeSoftwareSection] = Seq(CodeSoftwareSection("code", SoftwareAddress(0), 0))
  }
}

trait PeParserGetSectionsOfDataComp extends GetSectionsOfTypeComp {
  implicit val bar: GetSectionsOfType[DataSoftwareSection] = GetSectionOfData

  override def sectionsOfType[SectionType <: SoftwareSection](implicit evidence: GetSectionsOfType[SectionType]): GetSectionsOfType[SectionType] = evidence

  implicit object GetSectionOfData extends GetSectionsOfType[DataSoftwareSection] {
    override def getAll(dataStream: InputStream): Seq[DataSoftwareSection] = Seq(DataSoftwareSection("data", SoftwareAddress(0), 0))
  }
}
```

My business logic, located in the project `core` needs to call the method `sectionsOfType` of an instance of `GetSectionsOfType`, which will be gently injected using cake pattern.

## Issue to resolve the implicit type class

As the project `core` does not have (and should not have!) a dependency on the `infra` project, calling the method `sectionsOfType[CodeSoftwareSection].getAll(openStream)` makes the compiler angry, because it can't find any implicit value for the implicit parameter, which is normal!

Now, I can't just import all the implementations of `GetSectionsOfType` because it would expose the implementation in my project `core`. In order to resolve this situation, I read the article [WHERE DOES SCALA LOOK FOR IMPLICITS?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html) from the Scala docs, hoping to find another way to resolve my implicit, without creeping my project `core` with a dependency on my project `infra`.

Unfortunately, I could not find any way to resolve my implicit, as the project `core` can't link the project `infra` and the implicit parameters must be resolved at compile time.

Any proposal or alternative approach to keep the code clean ?

**EDIT 3**: Refactored the code with cake pattern.
**EDIT 4**: Add an example of call to the component in the project `core` below.

```
trait SoftwareComp {
  this: GetSectionsOfTypeComp =>

  class Software(val file: File) {

    def codeSections[SectionType <: SoftwareSection]: Seq[SectionType] = {
      sectionsOfType[SectionType].getAll(openStream)
    }

    def openStream: InputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some observations on your current code:

In your `GetSectionsOfTypeComp` you can write

```
trait GetSectionsOfTypeComp {
  def sectionsOfType[SectionType <: SoftwareSection](implicit evidence: GetSectionsOfType[SectionType]): GetSectionsOfType[SectionType] = evidence
}
```

if all you do is return the evidende in every (or at least many) implementations.

Also, you do not necessarily have to create an `implicit val` for you implicit objects.

This is definitely not a must but you can avoid creating subtypes for `GetSectionsOfTypeComp` and at the same time separate the type class code. You would end up with something of this kind:

```
import java.io.InputStream

// type class code
trait GetSectionsOfType[SectionType <: SoftwareSection] {
  def getAll(dataStream: InputStream): Seq[SectionType]
}

object GetSectionsOfType {
  implicit object GetSectionOfCode extends GetSectionsOfType[CodeSoftwareSection] {
    override def getAll(dataStream: InputStream): Seq[CodeSoftwareSection] = Seq(CodeSoftwareSection("code", SoftwareAddress(0), 0))
  }

  implicit object GetSectionOfData extends GetSectionsOfType[DataSoftwareSection] {
    override def getAll(dataStream: InputStream): Seq[DataSoftwareSection] = Seq(DataSoftwareSection("data", SoftwareAddress(0), 0))
  }
}

// component 
trait GetSectionsOfTypeComp {
  def sectionsOfType[SectionType <: SoftwareSection](implicit evidence: GetSectionsOfType[SectionType]): GetSectionsOfType[SectionType] = evidence
}
```

As for the actual question, I do not know all your code but you define the core project as a place for trait definitions. Is it a good idea for the core project to know about implementations? Should you not consider to place the calls elsewhere (e.g. a new module)? To decide this more knowledge about the call site would be required.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Étienne, many thanks for your answer! Good feedbacks. I initially used the `implicit val` to prevent any import in the code that uses `GetSectionsOfTypeComp `. This worked, but only within my `infra` project, because I can actually extends the traits `PeParserGetSectionsOfCodeComp ` and `PeParserGetSectionsOfDataComp `, for example in the unit tests. Unfortunately, it didn't work with the project `core`, as it has no reference to those implicit declarations.

Comment: For the second part of your answer, I try to follow the hexagonal architecture, where the models are declared in the core, alongside with the contracts for infrastructure concerns and create additional project per infrastructure concern, in this example the reading of the sections of a software. I have the feeling that the project `core` is not aware of the implementation, since the entity that calls the method `sectionsOfType` only rely on the trait `GetSectionsOfTypeComp` and not the actual implementation of the trait. I edited my question to include the calling part if this may help.